# Light background for Files with dark theme

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, themes

I want to have a dark theme like the one enabled with `gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` but I want Files to still have a light background.

Is this possible?

Many applications show light backgrounds with the dark variant enabled, including the native text editor Scratch, and most non-native applications only have a dark window bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to modify the stylesheet to use the desired `background-color` for the `view` class.

It's possible, but you'll probably create a bunch of issues trying to do this. Keep in mind also, that any updates you get to the system stylesheet will overwrite changes you've made locally.